# Pass string value to particular batch file code section using java

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to save a string value in batch file code , within a particular section. But I am unable to solve it yet .

This is a piece of **java code**:-

```
Button button = new Button("Click");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV File","csv");
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("");
                chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose");
                chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
                int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog((java.awt.Component) null);
                if ( returnVal == chooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
                    textField.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString());

                    String startfile="";
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(startfile);

                  final JFrame msgframe= new JFrame();
                      msgframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                      startfile=textField.getText(); 
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(chooser, startfile);

                   String outFile = startfile.substring(0, startfile.length()-".csv".length())+".xml";
```

I am picking the file path using chooser an storing it on the a string.

Now I need to pass that String that is ; 'outFile' to a particular section of a batch code .

**Batch file code :-**

```
@echo off
start java -jar D:\\xsd\fri.jar "C:/users/.../.../ddd.xml" > C:\Users\...\...\...\sdsd.txt
close
```

What is the approach to make changes on that particular section of batch file which is within `""`? I have a button and every time when I click it , a *XML* file is created on the same directory of the choose file.

Within `""` stores the XML file.

Comment: If I understand the question, you'd need to read the batch file in, manipulate the string, and then write it out again.

Comment: @SteveSmith can you tell me how to manipulate batch file strings using java .. Haven't interacted much with batch commands.

Comment: If I got you right, you could state `"%~1"` instead of the constant string in the batch file and run it with the actual path provided as a (quoted) command line argument...

Comment: @aschipfl the path may vary according to the file location. So i am just storing the path on string . Still not getting how to pass that string in the "%~1" location ?

Comment: The batch file should contain `start "" java -jar D:\\xsd\fri.jar "%~1" > C:\Users\...\...\...\sdsd.txt`, and the batch file is called with an argument like `batch-file.bat "C:/users/.../.../ddd.xml"`.By the way, there is no `close` command in batch, probably you mean `exit /B`, but it's superfluous here anyway...

Comment: @aschipfl This is clean , I am getting it , and I did exactly that you have mentioned earlier but "%~1" is referring to a string which I am parsing through java . Right? So , I am not getting that parsing concept\  the syntax. That' it.

Comment: The `%~1` part in the batch file is parsed and expanded to (replaced by) its actual value `C:/users/.../.../ddd.xml` before enything is executed, so Java receives the resolved path, it does not receive `%~1` literally...

Comment: @aschipfl Yes , I got that . I mean how can I store the string in `%~1` from the code . I need an example.

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks a lot , I solved this problem. You have mentioned `batch-file.bat "C:/users/.../.../ddd.xml"` . Here instead of `C:/users/.../.../ddd.xml` i passed that `outFile` string value and its done . Thank You again.

Comment: If you found a solution, please consider to post it as an answer, clearly describing what you are doing, as it might help future readers...